# Java Rect.intersects() not working sometimes

Tags: java, collision, rectangles

I currently loop through all my sprites checking if they intersect with each other like this:

```
for (Sprite s : sprites) {
        if (s.dead) {
            dead.add(s);
        }
        for (Sprite sprite : sprites) {
            if (!sprite.equals(s)) {
                s.collide(sprite, maxX, maxY);
            }
        }
        s.run();

}
```

and the sprite checks using the Rect.intersects() method like so:

```
if (getRect().intersects(s.getRect()))
```

But sometimes it just completely ignores a collision, and the objects just pass through each other.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is the sprite moving so fast that one check is done *before* the actual intersection, and the next one *after* the intersection, but none *during* the intersection? When in doubt, some `System.out.println` statements (or a debugger run) might help to figure out what's wrong there.

Comment: I added a check for a collision between frames and it works much better now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by making it create a rectangle for the area that it covers between frames like so:

```
private void checkForNextCollision() {
    double boundsWidth = width + dX ;
    if(dX < 0){
        boundsWidth= width - dX ;
    }

    double boundsHeight = height + dY ;
    if(dY < 0){
        boundsHeight = height - dY ;
    }
    double boundx = xWorld + dX ;
    double boundy = yWorld + dY ;
    betweenRect = new Rectangle((int)(boundx),(int)(boundy),(int)(boundsWidth), (int)(boundsHeight));


}
```

This rectangle is then checked against the rectangle created in the other sprites to check if there should be a collision in the next frame:

```
    public void collide(Sprite s, int maxX, int maxY) {
    maxWX = maxX;
    maxWY = maxY;


    //check for collision with borders
    if (xWorld <= 0) {
        dX = -dX;
        xWorld += 2;
        if(xWorld < -1000){
            dX = 0;
            xWorld += 10;
        }
    }
    if (yWorld <= 0) {
        dY = -dY;
        yWorld += 2;
        if(yWorld < -1000){
            dX = 0;
            yWorld += 10;
        }
    }
    if (xWorld + width >= maxX) {
        dX = -dX;
        xWorld -= 2;
        if(xWorld+width > maxX + 1000){
            dX = 0;
            xWorld -= 10;
        }
    }
    if (yWorld + height >= maxY) {
        dY = -dY;
        yWorld -= 2;
        if(yWorld+height > maxY + 1000){
            dY = 0;
            yWorld -= 10;
        }
    }



    //check for collision with borders
    if(betweenRect.intersects(s.betweenRect)){
        willIntersect = true;
    }else{
        willIntersect = false;
    }

    // Use all checks to see if they should collide
    if (getRect().intersects(s.getRect()) || s.getRect().intersects(getRect()) || willIntersect || (xWorld + width > s.xWorld && xWorld < s.xWorld + s.width && yWorld < s.yWorld+s.height && yWorld + height > s.yWorld) ) {

            double lastDy = dY;
            double lastsDy = s.dY;
            double lastDx = dX;
            double lastsDx = s.dX;

            dY = (((weight - s.weight) / (weight + s.weight)) * lastDy)
                    + (((2.0 * s.weight) / (weight + s.weight)) * lastsDy);
            s.dY = (((s.weight - weight) / (weight + s.weight)) * lastsDy)
                    + (((2.0 * weight) / (weight + s.weight)) * lastDy);

            dX = (((weight - s.weight) / (weight + s.weight)) * lastDx)
                    + (((2.0 * s.weight) / (weight + s.weight)) * lastsDx);
            s.dX = (((s.weight - weight) / (weight + s.weight)) * lastsDx)
                    + (((2.0 * weight) / (weight + s.weight)) * lastDx);



            if(willIntersect){
                willIntersect = false;
                //s.willIntersect = false;
            }


        }




}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try changing the code to

```
if(getRect().intersects(s.getRect()) || s.getRect().intersects(getRect()))
{
    // They have intersected
}
```

The reason for this being, the intersection method check is unique for each rectangle. Performing an intersection check to see if rectangle a intersects rectangle b, is different than performing an intersection check to see if rectangle b intersects rectangle a.

Other than this, can you give me more information on your rectangles? Are they rotating? How fast are they moving? How large are they? Other information would be use full as well, I can try to think of other reasons for why they are not colliding.